# Calling function from class without making New initialization - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I have two forms and set of functions created in a class. I have to call some functions from class from `Form1` and also used them in `Form2` with some values of variables stored in class from `Form1`, now I am using the following code on Form2:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            GetSetRequests reqClass = new GetSetRequests();
            MessageBox.Show(reqClass.RequestID.ToString());
        }
    }
```

`RequestID` is a variable created in a class `GetSetRequests`. Form1 stored value in it I have to use that value in form2 but this value become null because of New initialization of class. Is it possible to call the values and functions from class without making new initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the object from one of the forms to the other if you want both forms to share the same instance of an object.  Add an object of that type to the constructor of Form2, and when Form1 creates an instance of it then pass your GetSetRequests to it.

As mentioned by someone else, you could also give the class static properties instead, but that would mean it couldn't ever be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be static (or the keyword in VB.NET is more descriptive: `shared`). i.e the variable is shared between all instances of the `GetSetRequests` class. How ever, static/shared variables is a bad idea in most cases.

You should instead pass the `GetSetRequests` object from `Form1` to `Form2` and let both use the same instance.

You should read up on fundemental OOP principles since you ask that question. The follow article is for Java, but classes works in the same way in C#: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html